# .innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, innerhtml

I'm trying to validate a login page with a div to display the errors in , I'm using innerHTML to change the empty text in the div with the error occured , the problem is that the error msg is written and disappears just in a second

here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Sign up for a membership @ Ay 7aga.com
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
var x = "";
if(document.getElementById('user').value =="")
    x+="Enter user name -";
if(document.getElementById('password').value =="")
    x+="Enter password";
document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML = x;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div name="error" id="error" style="width:1200px;background-color:red"> 
<p name="error1" id="error1"> 
</div>
<center>
<br/>
<form name="register" id="register" >
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> UserName </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="user" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Password </td>
            <td> <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <button onclick="check()"> Submit </button>
</form>
<a href="Home page.html"> Go to Home page </a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the `check()` on the `<form onsubmit="return check();">` handler, and return `true` or `false` from `function check()`.

Comment: Also try not to use `.innerHTML` it is evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `<button>` tag, the "type" attribute is important: most browsers (correctly) default the type to "submit", which makes it work as a form submit element. You can instead set the type to "button", which makes the button have no native behavior other than to fire event handlers. Thus:

Thus:

```
<button onclick="check()" type=button>Submit</button>
```

will keep the button from causing an implicit submit of the form.

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching it the wrong way. What is probably happening is that your for is being submitted after click the login button, so that's why the text "disappears" in a couple of seconds.

Put your login checks on the server side, and generate HTML content for that specific scenario instead of using JavaScript.

BTW: what's that `<button>` tag you are using?

Comment: It's probably the `<button>` tag that's been in HTML forever :-)  The issue with the tag is that in some browsers the "type" attribute defaults to "submit". If the "type" is set to "button" then it won't trigger form submission.

Comment: +1 A button element is a submit one by default (if no `type` attribute given). http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Comment: I thought about the submitting issue , but I thought that since the button isn't of type submit then it won't be submitted .
I didn't notice the <button> thing until you wrote so :)
I forgot to make an attribute of type "button", this was the fault
thank you :)

Comment: @Pointy: wow! all these years writing HTML and never heard of the tag `<button>` before... Always used `<input type="button">`. Is it there for backward compatibility? Or is it newer than `<input type="button">`?

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz The nice thing about `<button>` is that you can wrap it around `<img>` tags etc; basically most inline content (kind of like `<a>`)

Comment: @Pointy you may write your comment as an answer to be marked as correct